# Position elements relative of a static sibling

Tags: css

I am working on a Calender where I have multiple events in parallel. I can allow the following elements in an event class to inherit their position form the event-start.

I would like the browser to handle the positioning of multiple elements.
When I set the position of the following elements to `absolute`
then the next event-start which has `position:relative;`, does see the element with absolute and get the same potion which means all events land in the same row.

Inherited Position with even-start a relative position.

[image: Calender Problem2]

Positions relative.

[image: Calender Problem]

Here is a fiddle without the inherit functionality.

https://jsfiddle.net/4uk8yur5/2/

I would like to, through css set the position of the events-start elements relative to the static events.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking; your question has some grammatical issues.

Comment: I would like to, through css set the position of the events-start elements relative to the static events element. Sat. black event I want a relative position to the (sameday) yellow event that has absolute position.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @user3400965 Do you want them on the same line, like your first image? Or on different lines, like the second image (except not all mixed up like they are now)?

Comment: Frankly it looks to me as though this is HTML structure related. That's a very odd way of structuring a calendar//timetable.

Comment: @Paulie_D I agree.

Comment: Offhand I suspect you'll need to rethink your HTML and add a shipload of JS.

Comment: What i would like is for the First Element of every Event to be like the second picture. Every Element in the Chain i have inhertiting the Position of the start Element. But then they require an absolute Position. A start of a new Event has a relative Position but it doesn't See the Element with absolute Position. There by they are all on one line.